# Can any player character features alter the base stats of weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons

Some spells, like [Elemental Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/elemental-weapon) and [Magic Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-weapon), change base stats of weapons. Are there any player character features that are not spells that alter the base stats of weapons?

Stats being any properties, Damage die size/type, magical or not, +1 +2 +3 etc.

I'm not asking to solve any particular problem, just out of curiosity.

I'm not looking for a list of all the effects that do so, just a simple yes/no backed up with at least one example. I'm looking for RAW and official examples. Please no UA.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101194/discussion-on-question-by-eternallord66-are-dice-from-the-divine-fury-feature-of).

Answer (score 8):

## Yes

At 1st level, the [Forge Cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#ForgeDomain) (XGtE, 19) can use their Artisan's blessing.

> At 1st level, you gain the ability to imbue magic into a weapon or armor. At the end of a long rest, you can touch one nonmagical object that is a suit of armor or a simple or martial weapon. Until the end of your next long rest or until you die, the object becomes a magic item, granting a +1 bonus to AC if it’s armor or a +1 bonus to attack and damage rolls if it’s a weapon.

Answer (score 7):

### The Monk's Martial Arts class feature is the classic example

At levels 5, 11, and 17, the damage die rolled for any monk weapon (any light weapon or a short sword) becomes d6, d8, and then a d10 respectively.
(PHB, The Monk, Table, page 77).

That changes the basic weapon's damage die using a class feature.

In the hands of a Monk, a dagger does 1d6 at 5th level (for others, it is still 1d4).  It does 1d10 at 17th level, which is the same damage as done two-handed with a longsword(versatile) by anyone else.

#### Warlock Pact of the Blade + Improved Pact Weapon

The basic feature from pact of the blade

> This weapon counts as magical for the purpose of overcoming
>   resistance and immunity to non magical attacks (PHB p. 107)

combined with

Improved Pact weapon  (Invocation)

> Prerequisite: Pact of the Blade feature
>   In addition, the weapon gains a +1 bonus to its Attack and Damage
>   Rolls, unless it is a Magic Weapon that already has a bonus to those
>   rolls. (xanathar's guide to everything)

Meets your criteria.

Is an invocation a class feature or a spell?  Invocations are a *class feature*, that sometimes grant a spell, sometimes an ability, and sometimes grants other things.